# RAM is full with only minimal apps running on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have 16GB of RAM installed in my system and almost 100% is in use with only minimal apps running. This is not normally how it should be, it usually hovers around 30-40%. It is so severe that Chrome is crashing with only a few tabs opened.

I have not recently installed any new drivers which makes it hard for me to trace down if a driver is causing it. Also booting into Windows 10 doesn't directly make it full right away. I am still observing which app might trigger it.

I scanned my computer using Bitdefender, and there was nothing out of the ordinary

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Take a look with RAMMap first: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap

Comment: I restarted my pc and it went back to normal for now, i will post a picture of rammap when it goes back up again

Comment: Also expand the Memory bar in Resource Monitor above. Many Chrome tabs (Browser tabs) use lots of memory. I am using 40% of 16 GB with two machines running (Windows 10 and Kali), so what you have is abnormal. Determine from the physical memory list in the above tool where it is going

Comment: If it was a temporary usage, Task Manager and I think Resource Monitor do that on startup for a couple of minutes

Comment: Just a couple guesses since you won't have evidence for a while: this is sometimes caused by a driver memory leak, or a process handle leak (including zombie processes), etc.. All things that cause memory allocation not obviously linked to a specific process and therefore not visible in Task Manager. RAMMap is the first step to getting an idea of what's causing it.

Comment: @Bob i think so too, and i think that the leak happens slowly since the restart it is slowly rising, currently at 7GB right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this somewhat an old question but how i solved this with no program install is go to

Task Manager - (More details) - Details Tab - Sort NP Pool From High to Low

[image]

Notice That one program is an unusually high NP pool right click that program and select "End Task". And wallah ! you got your RAM back.

Its a program from Razer, i have it because i have a Razer keyboard and i need their software to controll the RGB lights. Its leaking memory over a few days so you might not notice it right away.

Uninstall that program, if you must have it keep a look at its NP pool

Answer (score 1):

> It is so severe that chrome is crashing with only few tabs opened.

Chrome may be the issue.

Your screenshot shows chrome.exe seven times.

I know the obvious rebuttal: "Chrome didn't use to do that."  That isn't a good defense, unless you're using the same version of Chrome you always did, with the same content on the Internet.  If your Chrome automatically updated to a new version, or if any Internet sites might load different advertisements (including some which might contain different content than before, and possibly even content that is intentionally more malicious than before), then you're comparing caterpillars to butterflies, not apples to apples.

Get to a command prompt, and run:

`taskkill /f /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe"`

Then restart Chrome, and see if anything goes faster.

If that drastically improves speed, then that pretty well confirms what I suspect, which is that the issue is with Chrome, possibly caused by some web content that Chrome interacts with.  (I'm not saying that Chrome is guaranteed to be the only culprit.  But Chrome, possibly influenced by some content it interacts with, would appear to be a key culprit and maybe the only very significant one.)

While having that knowledge might not provide you with an instantly satisfying solution, at least it strongly puts blame on a more narrow scope, so you can stop wondering so much if other possible causes are most likely to be the main culprit.

Comment: Now that you mention it i do not know why chrome is there seven times. when the only tab that was opened in that time is me writing this question in superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have many foreground apps running, but you have LOTS of background apps running. Based on the size of the scroll bar, I'd say at least 400 in total, and only 50-60 would be built into Windows 10 itself. Very much a death by a thousand cuts situation. Go through your installed programs and start uninstalling anything unnecessary, or just refresh (or even reinstall fresh) to clear up everything that's been installed that isn't necessary.

Also, I'm curious if a piece of hardware or a bad driver is locking a significant portion of your memory. As in the comments, VMMap is the way to go to find out, since Task Manager can't show that.

Comment: I estimated a total for the process and it got me 6GB which is no where near my ram capacity, and i kid you not half of those processes are svchost.exe. I am suspecting a driver leaking memory ever so slowly thats why i wont notice it right away.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) =3.

For some reason, it did not show up in the process list, probably because of some virtualization technologies involved.